# Aplicar estilo a primeira linha após \n

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma `textarea` que recebera um texto. A aplicação de estilo será minima, por isso não queria utilizar algum editor como o CKEditor, por exemplo. 
Acredito que a forma mais fácil de trabalhar é aplicar um estilo ao item pós `/n`

Estarei recebendo um texto como o abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você pensa em usar para marcar o estilo do negritado?

Comment: Vou explicar um pouco melhor. No caso a ferramenta é praticamente um "gerador de html". Como processo final, vou exibir um código para o usuário. A marcação pode ser com <strong> por exemplo...

Comment: Por que não usa um editor WYSIWYG que use tags HTML apenas?

Comment: Aliás, o CKEditor permite a você configurar em que forma o HTML vai ser gerado, por exemplo: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/15-01-26-07-08/full/samples/plugins/htmlwriter/outputhtml.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode estar utilizando o `CSS ::first-line Selector`

Exemplo:

```css
div::first-line {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit. <br />
    Vestibulum erat velit, aliquet at mattis a, tristique ac mauris. <br />
    Quisque et neque quis lectus consequat ornare ut eu augue. <br />
    Praesent sapien massa, <br />
    </div>

    <div>
    Faucibus sed viverra a, ultrices eget velit. <br />
    Aliquam euismod ante eu est tempor posuere. <br />
    Duis semper sodales ligula, et lacinia libero iaculis ac. <br />
    Duis at elementum diam. Sed lectus justo, <br />
    Malesuada eget scelerisque vitae, ullamcorper eget enim. <br />
    Nulla vitae turpis luctus, consectetur velit non, mattis lorem. <br />
    </div>
```

Supondo que o texto com os `\n`, esteja assim:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit. \n
    Vestibulum erat velit, aliquet at mattis a, tristique ac mauris. \n
    Quisque et neque quis lectus consequat ornare ut eu augue. \n
    Praesent sapien massa, \n \n
    Faucibus sed viverra a, ultrices eget velit.\n
    Aliquam euismod ante eu est tempor posuere. \n
    Duis semper sodales ligula, et lacinia libero iaculis ac.\n
    Duis at elementum diam. Sed lectus justo, \n
    Malesuada eget scelerisque vitae, ullamcorper eget enim.\n
    Nulla vitae turpis luctus, consectetur velit non, mattis lorem.\n
```

Você terá que tratar os `\n`.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(texto)){
     texto = texto.Insert(0, "<div>");
     texto = texto.Replace("\n \n", "</div><div>");
     texto = texto.Insert(texto.Length, "</div>");
     texto = texto.Replace("\n", "<br />");
}
```

[Exemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mAegpL)

Comment: O problema é que eu vou estar recebendo um bloco de texto, vindo da minha textarea. O meu texto não estará dentro de uma div e sim abaixo de um /n

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa, fiz uma edição

Comment: Não funcionou dando replace em dois \n, mas funcionou da seguinte forma:

                Descricao = Descricao.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine, "</div><div>");